# How to delete a specific array element(array of array) in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

So I am trying to delete a specific element of the array which is present in an array
This is my data

I want to delete videoContent _id = x2

I want to update videoContent link = "x2x" where _id=x1

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxyyxx"),
    "name" : "Test",
    "subscribed" : [ 
        {
            "videoContent" : [ 
                {
                    "title" : "yyy",
                    "link" : "xxx",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("x1")
                },
                {
                    "title" : "yyy2",
                    "link" : "xxx2",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("x2")
                }
            ],
            "webinarContent" : [ 
                {
                    "title" : "yyy",
                    "link" : "xxx",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("y1")
                },
                {
                    "title" : "yyy2",
                    "link" : "xxx2",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("y2")
                }
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("4646464")
        }
    ]
}
```

I am from a SQL background I can't understand where conditions in mongodb.. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$pull` to delete an element from the list:

```
db.collection('collection').updateOne(
    { _id: ObjectId("xxyyxx") }, 
    { $pull: { "subscribed.videoContent._id": ObjectId("x2") }}
);
```

You can use `$set` with `arrayFilters` to update a double nested array item:

```
db.collection('collection').updateOne(
    { _id: ObjectId("xxyyxx") }, 
    { $set: { "subscribed.0.videoContent.$[content].link": "x2x" }},
    { arrayFilters: [{ 'content._id': ObjectId("x1") }]}
);
```

Comment: Thanks brother It works perfectly ! where I can learn these things